# Why do i get Error 0xC0000005 while using Kivy and Python?

Tags: python, kivy

i always get this error message while using kivy with pycharm. Using Pycharm without kivy works just fine.

I installed kivy like said on the website. I even reeinstalled my system but i still get this error message. I installed kivy, python and pycharm the same way on my notebook and it works just fine. Both systems run on windows 10 64 bit. The code is an example from a kivy tutorial: https://techwithtim.net/tutorials/kivy-tutorial/setup/. In my opinion it looks like i cant open OpelGL because that would be next when debugging

```py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text="tech with tim")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()`
```

```
C:\Python37\python.exe C:/Users/steph/PycharmProjects/project1/test.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\steph\.kivy\logs\kivy_19-05-20_42.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: Try uninstall and reinstall Python. When reinstalling checked `ADD PYTHON TO THE PATH`.

Comment: Hello, i solved this issue. I had two screens running. My second screen was using the graphic card of my mainboard. My first screen is using my amd graphic card. I had to deactivate my second screen using my main board graphic to run the application succesfully