# Kivy returns 'Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)' when run using usb dock

Tags: python, windows, kivy, sdl-2

I'm attempting to run a python script that displays a kivy window. I am using a wavlink usb dock to connect to two monitors, the following error occurs when connected to the wavlink usb dock.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\"user name"\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-04-17_49.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.3
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.4.5
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

The code I am using is:

```
from kivy.app import App


class CoreApp(App):
    pass


CoreApp().run()
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled my graphics drivers, with no change. Connecting to an external monitor directly using an HDMI chord works. I am using Python 3.10, which I redownloaded. My IDE is Pycharm, but the error occurs when the script is made into an executable with pyinstaller as well. My computer is an ASUS Vivobook, running windows 11.

Edit: I ran the same code, using the FaultHandler module,

```
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x000039ec (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 306 in create_window
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 1071 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 165 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 71 in core_select_lib
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 2460 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027 in _find_and_load
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 136 in ensure_window
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 341 in __init__
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 597 in build
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 924 in _run_prepare
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 954 in run
  File "C:\Users\"user name"\minimal-reproducable-error\minimumError.py", line 12 in <module>
```

Comment: I don't suppose the "I fixed it" comment from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56226366/why-do-i-get-error-0xc0000005-while-using-kivy-and-python helps any? Having said that, if I search the web for "kivy 0xC0000005" I get a whole bunch of results, including quite a few Stackoverflow posts, did none of those help?

Comment: Unfortunately they didn't.